# How to partitions space between n pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, partitioning

We are using Kubernetes and we need to do "Smart partitioning" of data. We want to split the space between 1 to 1000 between n running Pods, 
And each pod should know which part of the space is his to handle (for pooling partitioned tasks).

So for example, if we have 1 pod he will handle the whole space from 1-1000.

When we scale out to 3 pods, each of them will get the same share.

Pod 1 - will handle 1-333

Pod 2 - 334-667

Pod 3 667-1000

Right now the best way that we find to handle this issue is to create a Stateful-set, that pooling the number of running pods and his instance number and decide which part of the space he needs to handle.
Is there a smarter/built-in way in Kubernetes to partition the space between nodes in this manner?

Service fabric has this feature built-in.

Comment: IMHO, statefulset is the best approach so far.

Comment: @Amir Harari - I'm curios how do you handle changes in the number of replicas in the stateful set scenario?

Comment: Each pod We will periodically pool from the master the number of running pods and change the space he is responsible for accordingly. @Amityo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **NO** native tools for scaling at the [partition level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-scalability#scaling-at-the-partition-level) in K8s yet.

Only custom solutions similar to what you have came up with in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Provide another customized way for doing this for your reference. Based on this [tech blog of Airbnb](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/dynein-building-a-distributed-delayed-job-queueing-system-93ab10f05f99)

> Given the list of pods and their names, each pod is able to
> deterministically calculate a list of partitions that it should work
> on. When we add or remove pods from the ReplicaSet, the pods will
> simply pick up the change, and work on the new set of partitions
> instead

How do they do is based on the [their repo](https://github.com/airbnb/dynein). I summarized the key components here (Note: the repo is written in Java).

1. Get how many pods running in the k8s namespace, and sort by pod name ([code](https://github.com/airbnb/dynein/blob/2b3164ad0c578f3693449fb58e65a376ca7ebaba/dynein/src/main/java/com/airbnb/dynein/scheduler/partition/K8SConsecutiveAllocationPolicy.java#L35)). Code snippet

```
String podName = System.getenv("K8S_POD_NAME");
String namespace = System.getenv("K8S_NAMESPACE");
NamespacedKubernetesClient namespacedClient = kubernetesClient.inNamespace(namespace);
ReplicaSet replicaSet;

// see above code link to know how to get activePods, remove it here because it is too long

int podIndex = activePods.indexOf(podName);
int numPods = activePods.size();
```

2. Every time you call the above code, you will have deterministic list of `podIndex` and `numPods`. Then, using this information to calculate the range this pod is responsible for

```
List<Integer> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
int split = spaceRange / numPods;
int start = podIndex * split;
int end = (podIndex == numPods - 1) ? spaceRange - 1 : ((podIndex + 1) * split) - 1;
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
  partitions.add(i);
}
```

3. Since the number of pods will be changed anytime, you may need a `executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay` to periodically update the list as [here](https://github.com/airbnb/dynein/blob/2b3164ad0c578f3693449fb58e65a376ca7ebaba/dynein/src/main/java/com/airbnb/dynein/scheduler/worker/WorkerManager.java#L39)

```
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::updatePartitions, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This approach is not the best, since if you set scheduleWithFixedDelay with 30 seconds, any pod change won't be captured within 30 seconds. Also, it is possible in a short period of time, two pods may be responsible for the same space, and you need to handle this special case in your business logics as Airbnb tech blog does.